# How to generate a custom cross-validation generator in scikit-learn?

Tags: python, validation, scikit-learn, svm

I have an unbalanced dataset, so I have an strategy for oversampling that I only apply during training of my data. I'd like to use classes of scikit-learn like `GridSearchCV` or `cross_val_score` to explore or cross validate some parameters on my estimator(e.g. SVC). However I see that you either pass the number of cv folds or an standard cross validation generator.

I'd like to create a custom cv generator so I get and Stratified 5 fold and oversample only my training data(4 folds) and let scikit-learn look through the grid of parameters of my estimator and score using the remaining fold for validation.

Comment: did u find solution for this?

Comment: Yeah, I will post it this week.

Comment: thanks! please do post so that it helps people like me :p

Comment: i would really like to see your solution, i am stuck on this one as well.

Answer (score 25):

The cross-validation generator returns an iterable of length `n_folds`, each element of which is a 2-tuple of numpy 1-d arrays `(train_index, test_index)` containing the indices of the test and training sets for that cross-validation run.

So for 10-fold cross-validation, your custom cross-validation generator needs to contain 10 elements, each of which contains a tuple with two elements:

- An array of the indices for the training subset for that run, covering 90% of your data
- An array of the indices for the testing subset for that run, covering 10% of the data

I was working on a similar problem in which I created integer labels for the different folds of my data. My dataset is stored in a Pandas dataframe `myDf` which has the column `cvLabel` for the cross-validation labels.  I construct the custom cross-validation generator `myCViterator` as follows:

```
myCViterator = []
for i in range(nFolds):
    trainIndices = myDf[ myDf['cvLabel']!=i ].index.values.astype(int)
    testIndices =  myDf[ myDf['cvLabel']==i ].index.values.astype(int)
    myCViterator.append( (trainIndices, testIndices) )
```

Comment: Wouldn't this column (`cvLabel`) be included as a useless feature in the training and testing?

Comment: Good observation @GerardoFigueroa; I create this column to help with CV generation, then subset `myDf` to strip this column (and any other irrelevant features) from the dataset which is sent to the predictor.

Answer (score 18):

I had a similar problem and this quick hack is working for me:

```
class UpsampleStratifiedKFold:
    def __init__(self, n_splits=3):
        self.n_splits = n_splits

    def split(self, X, y, groups=None):
        for rx, tx in StratifiedKFold(n_splits=self.n_splits).split(X,y):
            nix = np.where(y[rx]==0)[0]
            pix = np.where(y[rx]==1)[0]
            pixu = np.random.choice(pix, size=nix.shape[0], replace=True)
            ix = np.append(nix, pixu)
            rxm = rx[ix]
            yield rxm, tx

    def get_n_splits(self, X, y, groups=None):
        return self.n_splits
```

This upsamples (with replacement) the minority class for a balanced `(k-1)`-fold training set, but leaves `k`th test set unbalanced.  This appears to play well with [`sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html) and other similar classes requiring a CV generator.

Answer (score 12):

Scikit-Learn provides a workaround for this, with their Label k-fold iterator:

> **LabelKFold** is a variation of k-fold which ensures that the same label is not in both testing and training sets. This is necessary for example if you obtained data from different subjects and you want to avoid over-fitting (i.e., learning person specific features) by testing and training on different subjects.

To use this iterator in a case of oversampling, first, you can create a column in your dataframe (e.g. `cv_label`) which stores the index values of each row.

```
df['cv_label'] = df.index
```

Then, you can apply your oversampling, making sure you copy the `cv_label` column in the oversampling as well. This column will contain duplicate values for the oversampled data. You can create a separate series or list from these labels for handling later:

```
cv_labels = df['cv_label']
```

Be aware that you will need to remove this column from your dataframe before running your cross-validator/classifier.

After separating your data into features (not including `cv_label`) and labels, you create the `LabelKFold` iterator and run the cross validation function you need with it:

```
clf = svm.SVC(C=1)
lkf = LabelKFold(cv_labels, n_folds=5)
predicted = cross_validation.cross_val_predict(clf, features, labels, cv=lkf)
```

Comment: Renamed to [GroupKFold](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold.html#sklearn.model_selection.GroupKFold) in 0.18.

Answer (score -4):

```
class own_custom_CrossValidator:#like those in source sklearn/model_selection/_split.py 
    def init(self):#coordinates,meter 
        pass # self.coordinates = coordinates # self.meter = meter 
    def split(self,X,y=None,groups=None):
    #for compatibility with #cross_val_predict,cross_val_score 
        for i in range(0,len(X)): yield tuple((np.array(list(range(0,len(X))))
```